# How to eliminate xterm flickering on a slow machine?

Tags: linux, flicker, xterm

When scrolling back, xterm window flickers while updating its contents. The same occurs if a program produces much output that is continuously written to the terminal.

I searched man pages and google, but found nothing like dobule-buffering in xterm. Is there any way to enable such feature? How to prevent text from flickering?

(I am sure that most of you don't have this problem, but I work on very old integrated video card and every lightweight program works rather fine, except the xterm, which annoys me a bit...)

Comment: What does this have to do with coding?

Comment: Enable `double-buffering` in `xterm`

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: @hek2mgl How? Is that compilation-time or run-time option?

Comment: @smiszym Unfortunately I don't know that.. It is already enabled on my system. But double buffering is meant to prevent from flickering.. What system are you using?

Comment: @hek2mgl I use Arch. But it's alright now, I found the option in `configure` script. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to compile `xterm` from source, with `--enable-double-buffer` option passed to `./configure` script. Then simple `make && make install` (but, as @hek2mgl noticed, the feature is enabled by default in some systems)

Comment: On Debian (and derivatives as Ubuntu): `apt build-dep xterm` `cd ~/workdir` `apt source xterm` `cd xterm-353` `/.configure --enable-double-buffer` `make` `sudo make install`

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem - xterm was scrolling very slowly and even taking about half a second to display a character after i type in. changing the window manager from `mutter` to `metacity` fixed this.